# Headless Unity return error Multiple Unity instances

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, build-server

I have installed Unity 2021.3.15f1 on EC2 Amazon, AWS Linux. I am trying to run unity build using commands and flag to use batchmode, but even I am invoking the command only once, there is a message

```
It looks like another Unity instance is running with this project open.

Multiple Unity instances cannot open the same project.

Project: /repo/VR-Survival
Fatal Error! It looks like another Unity instance is running with this project open.

Multiple Unity instances cannot open the same project.
```

I've checked if there is any process of Unity, but no. Restarts of EC2 instance doesn't help either. Any ideas how to solve this?

Command:  `xvfb-run /home/ec2-user/Editor/Unity -batchmode -nographics -projectPath /repo/VR-Survival/ -quit -logfile ~/editor.log -serial [my serial number] -username pawelmalysz@xxx.com -password my_password`

Full logs (censored)

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxxx ~]$ cat editor.log
Unity Editor version:    2021.3.15f1 (e8e88683f834)
Branch:                  2021.3/staging
Build type:              Release
Batch mode:              YES
System name:             Linux
Distro version:          #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Aug  1 20:47:25 UTC 2023
Kernel version:          6.1.41-63.114.amzn2023.x86_64
Architecture:            x86_64
Available memory:        15779 MB
User pawelmalysz@xxxx.com logged in successfully
[LicensingClient] Channel doesn't exist: "LicenseClient-ec2-user"
[Licensing::Module] Successfully launched the LicensingClient (PId: 2200)
No usable version of libssl was found
[LicensingClient] Channel doesn't exist: "LicenseClient-ec2-user"
[Licensing::Module] Timed-out after 60.00s, waiting for channel: "LicenseClient-ec2-user"
IPC channel to LicensingClient doesn't exist; falling back to Legacy licensing

LICENSE SYSTEM [202391 9:1:38] Next license update check is after 2023-08-19T08:54:23


LICENSE SYSTEM [202391 9:1:38] Current license is already valid and activated. Skipping license activation process (Provided username/password will be ignored).
Pro License: YES
Initialize udev device monitor.
[Package Manager] Server::Start -- Port 42797 was selected

COMMAND LINE ARGUMENTS:
/home/ec2-user/Editor/Unity
-batchmode
-nographics
-projectPath
/repo/VR-Survival/
-quit
-logfile
/home/ec2-user/editor.log
-serial
(hidden)
-username
pawelmalysz@xxxx.com
-password
(hidden)
-executeMethod
/repo/VR-Survival/Assets/Editor/Scripts/BuildScript.cs
Successfully changed project path to: /repo/VR-Survival/
/repo/VR-Survival
It looks like another Unity instance is running with this project open.

Multiple Unity instances cannot open the same project.

Project: /repo/VR-Survival
Fatal Error! It looks like another Unity instance is running with this project open.

Multiple Unity instances cannot open the same project.

Project: /repo/VR-Survival
```

Script:

```
using UnityEditor;

public class BuildScript
{
    public static void BuildLinux()
    {
        string[] scenes = { "Assets/Scenes/SplashSceen", "Assets/Scenes/MainMenu", "Assets/Scenes/Oregano", "Assets/Scenes/OtherScene" };
        string buildPath = "/home/ec2-user/SNBuild";
        Console.Log("TEST TEST");
        Debug.Log("TEST 2 Test 2");
        BuildReport buildReport = BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(scenes, buildPath, BuildTarget.StandaloneLinux64, BuildOptions.None);

        if (buildReport.summary.result == BuildResult.Succeeded)
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Build completed successfully.");
        }
        else
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("Build failed. Error: " + buildReport.summary);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas what should I try or where should I look for an answer?

Comment: Check if a Temp folder exists with a UnityLockFile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the Temp folder helped.